# Import text file as UTF-8

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8

I am using the following vba code to import all **txt files** in the active directory into excel.

```
Sub ImportTXTfiles()
Dim Path As String

Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.txt")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Sheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

However my txt files are in UTF-8 character encoding. How can I import them using the above code but in UTF-8 code?

I tried to use this:

```
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      .Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
End With
```

but without success. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: See [How to decode UTF8 in VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29980993/4088852). It's exactly the same in VBA as VB6.