# Special Characters from txt file to excel

Tags: excel, special-characters, vba

I am trying to import special characters from a txt file into excel.
I've tried so many things but the characters BREAK in excel.
example of my string:

in txt: Changjíhuízúzìzhìzhou
converts in excel to: ChangjÃ­huÃ­zÃºzÃ¬zhÃ¬zhou

so I tried moving values over bit by bit but no luck..

```
Sub ImportTXTFile()

Dim file As Variant
Dim EXT As String
Dim Direct As String    ' directory...
Direct = "C:\FilePath\Here\"
EXT = ".txt"
Dim COL As Long
Dim row As Long
COL = 1
row = 1

file = Dir(Direct)

Do While (file <> "")   ' Cycle through files until no more files
    If InStr(file, "Data.txt") > 0 Then 
        '
        Open Direct & "Data.txt" For Input As #1               
        '
        While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, DataLine ' Read in line
            Do While DataLine <> ""
                If InStr(DataLine, ",") = 0 Then    ' Drop value into excel upto the first ,
                    Sheets("test").Cells(row, COL).Value = DataLine
                    DataLine = ""
                Else
                    Sheets("test").Cells(row, COL).Value = Left(DataLine, InStr(DataLine, ",") - 1)
                    DataLine = Right(DataLine, Len(DataLine) - InStr(DataLine, ","))    ' rebuild array without data upto first ,
                End If
                COL = COL + 1   ' next column
            Loop
            COL = 1             ' reset column
            row = row + 1       ' write to next row
        Wend
        '
        Close #1    ' Close files straight away
    End If
    file = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "Data Updated"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried reading it as [UTF-8](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/read-write-utf8/)? Or another format? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085572/7690982). A quote from the first link `The File System Object, generally used by VBScript developers to read and write text files, can read only ASCII or Unicode text files. You cannot use it to read or write UTF-8 encoded text files.`

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to test this but am having issues with MultiByteToWideChar function...is this even a real thing anymore?

Answer (score 2):

So I want to cry because all this converting of UTF-8 to ASCII can be avoid simply by:
opening the txt file in Notepad++ 
going to the encoding tab
clicking convert to ASCII

ran my original code.
BLAM
everything is perfect.

Thank you danieltakeshi for all your help!

Comment: _There is no text but encoded text._ You can't read a text file without knowing its encoding. In VB, VBA and VBScript, ADODB.Stream is the right library to use to apply that knowledge. [@danieltakeshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491217/2226988).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [first link](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/read-write-utf8/) i gave you, here is a test code, i tested with success. Using the [charset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526296(v=exchg.10).aspx): [CdoISO_8859_1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Dim objStream As Object
Dim strData As String
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile ("C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\test.txt")
strData = objStream.ReadText()
Debug.Print strData & " Compare to: Changjíhuízúzìzhìzhou"
```

The output was: [image: immediate]

#### EDIT:

Check the encoding type of your .txt file and import to Excel with the same encoding charset, for example, i changed the test.txt to UTF-8 and imported successfully with the .Charset as `"utf-8"`

You can Save As your .txt file and choose the encoding.

[image: .txt save as]

Comment: I've implemented your sample code into what I currently have.
But when I track the variable recieving the characters, I see it loading into memory as ChangjÃ­huÃ­zÃºzÃ¬zhÃ¬zhou
and it continues to print into excel as ChangjÃ­huÃ­zÃºzÃ¬zhÃ¬zhou

Could there be a setting I'm leaving out?