# Converting Unicode into UTF-8 in Visual Basic 6

Tags: mysql, excel, vb6

I try to import Unicode data from a Visual Basic 6 [Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) file into a MySQL table. The data contains [Polish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Polish#Adjective) characters. The problem is that instead of Polish characters I got garbage in the MySQL table.

The import procedure looks like this:

```
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & T_BAZA & ";Persist Security Info=False"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Set db1 = New ADODB.Connection
db1.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & "SERVER=192.168.101.1;" & " DATABASE=jadlospis1;" & "UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;OPTION=3;"
Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset


Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass

SQL1 = "DELETE FROM Jadlospis;"
db1.Execute SQL1, , adCmdText

SQL = "SELECT NazwaJadlospisu, Dzien, Posilek, PotrawaProdukt, Waga, Opis, Komentarz FROM JadlospisSzczegoly ORDER BY NazwaJadlospisu, Dzien, Posilek, PotrawaProdukt"
rst.Open SQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do While Not rst.EOF
            t_wiersz = t_wiersz + 1

            t_NazwaJadlospisu = (LCase(rst("NazwaJadlospisu")))
            t_Dzien = (LCase(rst("Dzien")))
            t_Posilek = (LCase(rst("Posilek")))
            t_PotrawaProdukt = (LCase(rst("PotrawaProdukt")))
            T_Waga = (LCase(rst("Waga")))
            t_opis = (LCase(rst("Opis")))
            t_Komentarz = (LCase(rst("Komentarz")))

            SQL1 = "INSERT INTO Jadlospis ( NazwaJadlospisu, Dzien, Posilek, PotrawaProdukt, Komentarz, Waga, Opis ) VALUES ( '" & t_NazwaJadlospisu & "', " & t_Dzien & ", " & t_Posilek & ", '" & t_PotrawaProdukt & "', '" & t_Komentarz & "', " & T_Waga & ", '" & t_opis & "' );"
            db1.Execute SQL1, , adCmdText
            rst.MoveNext
Loop
db1.Close
rst.Close
db.Close
```

The MySQL table has been created with the DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 option. The problem is that instead of Polish characters, I got garbage in the MySQL table, i.e., the table shows as follows:

```
+------------------------------+
| NazwaJadlospisu              |
+------------------------------+
| dieta 1500 kcal              |
| dieta wegaÅ„ska 1500 kcal    |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And it should show like this:

```
+------------------------------+
| NazwaJadlospisu              |
+------------------------------+
| dieta 1500 kcal              |
| dieta wegańska 1500 kcal    |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried a few functions available on the Internet, but none of them worked.

The general question is: How do I convert [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) into the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character set in Visual Basic 6?

Since I can export the data into an Excel spreadsheet or other format, the other question would be: How can I load the data into a MySQL table from an Excel spreadsheet or other (for example, .txt) format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the character set when you open the connection to the MySQL database, so that everything is utf8 encoded.

Add to your connection string:

```
charset=UTF8;
```

Like described in *[Specifying character set using MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-3-51/specifying-character-set/)*

When that is taken care of you are facing the problem that Windows has everything in Unicode and that is of course not utf8.

But Stack Overflow question *[How can I decode UTF8 in Visual Basic 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980993)* provides an answer to that.

Read the whole of the answers. At the end there is also an encoding function, and you need both.

Comment: I have updated the connect string with "charset=UTF8;" string and added UTF8ENCODE function as described. It works fine. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: you are welcome. Vb6 is old, it haven't programmed it in more than 10 years. You should  think about switching to vb net.